# Problems to get a remote shell variable

Tags: shell, ssh, variable-assignment, heredoc

I have a problem with an execution of a shell script into a remote shell.

I can't get value of $ARQ_END.

```
ssh -T user@MACHINE << 'EOSSH'

/app/work/leo/ReturnFileName.sh #This script returns a filename like: ADDRESS_BR_RECIFE_20170913.txt
ARQ_END="`/app/work/leo/ReturnFileName.sh`"
EOSSH

echo $ARQ_END #Returns nothing! Expected to return: ADDRESS_BR_RECIFE_20170913.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting a variable in a subshell isn't visible in the parent shell. You need to set the variable directly in the parent shell. The way to do that is to pass the output of `ReturnFileName.sh` up through the ssh session and to the parent shell and capture it there.

```
ARQ_END=$(ssh user@MACHINE /app/work/leo/ReturnFileName.sh)
echo "$ARQ_END"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works!
I used the case as you posted:

```
ARQ_END=$(ssh user@MACHINE /app/work/leo/ReturnFileName.sh)
echo "$ARQ_END"
```